# JavaScript discord bot keeps going offline with keep alive

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I have a Javascript discord bot, and it is getting bigger and bigger, the problem is that every time I close my replit. In about 30 minutes my bot just goes offline.
I use this code in my keep_alive.js file

````
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write("Online:)");
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);```

//I have this in index.js: `const keep_alive = require('./keep_alive.js')`
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution that I have found and use (and it is free) is pm2. It requires no code in your file at all

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/

```
npm i pm2 -g

// navigate to the folder with your main bot.js file (in this example it is called index.js)

pm2 start index.js

// followed by

pm2 save

// Optionally you can monitor the whole server as well with

pm2-server-monit
```

Comes with a free dashboard as well

Answer (score 1):

You could use freshping to keep the bot online if you use replit or something like that. You just need this like website you can monitor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).